# scanf(), Linux's shell input in handled differently, why?

Tags: c, linux, shell, scanf

I got the following.

`my-app.c` file:

```
char username[USERNAME_MAX_LEN] = "\0";
char password[PASSWORD_MAX_LEN] = "\0";
scanf("%s %s", username, password);
printf("username-len: %ld, password-len: %ld\n", strlen(username), strlen(password));
```

`credentials.data` file:

```
jdons f4$dsef35fs
```

So:

```
$ ./my-app < credentials.data
username-len: 0, password-len: 0
```

and:

```
$ cat credentials.data | ./my-app
username-len: 5, password-len: 10
```

- Why in the both ways the input is handled differently? What is the difference to be so?
- What is the right way to use `scanf()` to be able to handle both cases in the same way?

Comment: **This shouldn't happen**. You are doing something else in the real code. I suspect this is a "simplification" that you didn't actually try.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it any more, very strange. Seems it was kind of something abnormal. Now the case above works ok. Thanks everyone!

Comment: It's clearer to use `""` rather than `"\0"` to initialize your character arrays.  (This is not relevant to your problem, just a style point.)

Comment: Ignoring the return value of scanf lost information that could have been useful. In my experience, scanf is too picky about input that is not exactly as expected and most would be better off forgetting it exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Barankin,

Hmmm... that's an interesting behavior.

Both standard input indirection techniques work (as expected) for me...

```
landkrc@lasun175:/home/user/landkrc/crap
$ cat lg.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>

#define USERNAME_MAX_LEN 36
#define PASSWORD_MAX_LEN 36

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        printf("Hello, world\n");
        char username[USERNAME_MAX_LEN]; 
        char password[PASSWORD_MAX_LEN]; 
        *username = 0;
        *password = 0;
        scanf("%s %s", username, password); 
        printf("username-len: %ld, password-len: %ld\n", strlen(username), strlen(password)); 
        return 0;
}

landkrc@lasun175:/home/user/landkrc/crap
$ cc -V       
cc: Sun C 5.8 2005/10/13
usage: cc [ options] files.  Use 'cc -flags' for details

landkrc@lasun175:/home/user/landkrc/crap
$ cc -o lg lg.c

landkrc@lasun175:/home/user/landkrc/crap
$ echo '12345678 1234567890
> ' >data.txt

landkrc@lasun175:/home/user/landkrc/crap
$ lg <data.txt
username-len: 8, password-len: 10

landkrc@lasun175:/home/user/landkrc/crap
$ cat data.txt | lg
username-len: 8, password-len: 10
```

**Maybe you just need an end-of-line-character on the end of your `credentials.data` file?**

Cheers. Keith.

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
scanf("%s %s", username, password);
```

is inherently unsafe (unless you have complete control over what will appear on your program's standard input).  The `"%s"` format says to read an *arbitrarily long* sequence of non-whitespace characters.  However long the target array is, a sufficiently long word (say, caused by your cat sitting on the keyboard) will overflow it.

You can use a length modifier to limit the size of the input.  For example (untested):

```
scanf("%36s %36s", username, password);
```

or, better:

```
scanf("%*s, %*s", USERNAME_MAX_LEN, username, PASSWORD_MAX_LEN, password);
```

But it's probably better to use `fgets()` to read an entire line at a time, and then use, say, `sscanf()` to process the line after you've read it.

And there's a possible problem in your `printf` call:

```
printf("username-len: %ld, password-len: %ld\n",
       strlen(username),
       strlen(password));
```

`strlen()` returns a result of type `size_t`, but `"%ld"` requires an argument of type `long int`.  If your system supports it, you can use `"%zu"` to print a value of type `size_t`, but that's not 100% portable.  Or you can convert the `size_t` value to, say, unsigned long:

```
printf("username-len: %lu, password-len: %lu\n",
       (unsigned long)strlen(username),
       (unsigned long)strlen(password));
```

It's possible, but not very likely, that that could cause non-zero `size_t` values to be displayed as 0.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your credentials.data contains a a newline character at the end?   cat command appends it after the last line of file automatically.

Comment: A newline isn't necessary as `scanf` will still receive an `EOF`.

Answer (score 0):

As much as I try, I can't manage to reproduce the same problem as you. I even manually removed the end of line byte from the `credentials.data` file and it still works fine (as it should). What version of Linux or the shell are you running?